# Calculate raster cell area as function of latitude?

Tags: raster, r, latitude-longitude, area

Raster used available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xn7hdll2op5zcc9/MAP_global.tif?dl=0.

**INTRODUCTION:**
The resolution of a raster is commonly related in degrees, e.g.:

```
   library(raster)
   r <- raster("/CALL/IN/RASTER/FILE")
   print(r)

   class      : RasterLayer 
   dimensions : 720, 1440, 1036800  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
   *resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)*
   extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
   crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
   source     : MAP_global.tif 
   names      : MAP_global 
   values     : 2.561833, 10341.26  (min, max)
```

At the equator, x = 0.25 degrees is ~27.75km, so, a 0.25 x 0.25 cell would have a horizontal area of ~770.06km^2. While the resolution (in units of degree) will remain constant as a function of latitude, the grid cell's area will shrink with distance from the equator.

**QUESTION:**

Can the area of a 0.25 x 0.25 degree grid cell be calculated as a function of latitude, and then be stored as a variable in that raster? If so, could someone please provide that script? Or provide me the information needed to proceed with coding it myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the raster packages "area" function!

Make a sample lat-long raster (1 degree here but any lat-long raster should work):

```
> r = raster()
> r
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 180, 360, 64800  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

and `area` gives us:

```
> area(r)
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 180, 360, 64800  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 107.7756, 12308.62  (min, max)
```

a raster where each cell is the area in km^2, approximately. See the help for details of the approximation.

Answer (score 3):

Just a little remark: `{terra}` seems to handle things a little bit differently in comparison to `{raster}` since `area()` was removed from the package. `expanse()` is now what you are looking for:

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.6.33

# init raster
r <- rast(resolution = 0.25)

# insert some unique values to remove NAs
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)

r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 720, 1440, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#> source(s)   : memory
#> name        :   lyr.1 
#> min value   :       1 
#> max value   : 1036800

# area per grid cell
res <- expanse(r, unit = "km", byValue = TRUE)

summary(res[, 3])
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>   1.701 298.578 547.647 491.961 711.836 769.316
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution employing terra. It is an interesting alternative to the one suggested by SpacedMan. Unfortunately, I can only choose one solution as the 'answer', else I would flag both your's and SpacedMan's solutions. Because SpacedMan provided a solution first, I'm flagging that solution the answer. That said, I do appreciate your time and have certainly learned something - thanks!

Comment: No worries, just wanted to provide some additional info to the existing answer.